# Drope false levels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following plot:

[image: ggplot]

There I plot the fitted values of a data frame with each level of the factor of `Serial_number`. 
I would like to get rid of all the levels which are false, meaning, only the Serial_number with 608004650 shows up.

The code:

```
> head(APD)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  Serial_number    Lot  Wafer Amplification Voltage Dark_current     pred
         <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>         <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl>
1     608004648      6    608       111.997 379.980     0.386364 1.550965
2     608004648      6    608       123.673 381.968     0.381323 1.572166
3     608004648      6    608       137.701 383.979     0.411581 1.594672
4     608004648      6    608       154.514 385.973     0.460648 1.618040
5     608004648      6    608       175.331 387.980     0.506632 1.642617
6     608004648      6    608       201.379 389.968     0.554607 1.668009

fit<- lmer(log(log(Amplification)) ~ poly(Voltage, 2) + (poly(Voltage, 2) | Serial_number), data = APD)
APD$pred<- fitted(fit)

ggplot(APD, aes(x = Voltage, y = log(log(Amplification)), colour = Serial_number==608004650)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  geom_line(aes(y = fitted(fit)),size=1)
```

edit: Missing code lines to understand the data construction:

```
Limit data ranges:

APD.frame$Threshold<- "No"
APD.frame$Threshold[APD.frame$Amplification <= 150]<- "Yes"
APD.frame <- within(APD.frame,{
  Threshold <- factor(Threshold)
})


  APDmin<- APD.frame %>% group_by(Serial_number, Threshold)  %>% top_n(n, Amplification)
  APDmin<- APDmin[!APDmin$Threshold == "No", ]
  APDmax<- APD.frame %>% group_by(Serial_number, Threshold)  %>% top_n(-n, Amplification)
  APDmax<- APDmax[!APDmax$Threshold == "Yes", ]
  APD<- rbind(APDmin, APDmax)
  APD<- with(APD, APD[order(Serial_number, Amplification),])
  APD$Threshold<- NULL
```

Minimal reproducible example (34 code lines + part of the data (~ 270 lines)): https://ufile.io/345np

edit: When I don't remove the `Threshold` column and apply the same plot commands I now get:

```
str(APD.frame <- read.table("4_APDs_irradiated.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "", dec = "."))

APD.frame <- within(APD.frame,{
  Serial_number <- factor(Serial_number)
  Irradiated <- factor(Irradiated, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("no", "yes"))
})
APD.frame$Irradiated<- NULL

library(dplyr)
library(lme4)

APD.frame$Threshold<- "No"
APD.frame$Threshold[APD.frame$Amplification <= 150]<- "Yes"

n = 3
APDmin<- APD.frame %>% group_by(Serial_number, Threshold)  %>% top_n(n, Amplification)
APDmin<- APDmin[!APDmin$Threshold == "No", ]
APDmax<- APD.frame %>% group_by(Serial_number, Threshold)  %>% top_n(-n, Amplification)
APDmax<- APDmax[!APDmax$Threshold == "Yes", ]
APD<- rbind(APDmin, APDmax)
APD<- with(APD, APD[order(Serial_number, Amplification),])

summary(fit<- lmer(log(log(Amplification)) ~ poly(Voltage, 2) + (poly(Voltage, 2) | Serial_number), data = APD))

APD$pred<- fitted(fit)

APD %>% filter(Serial_number == "912009895") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Voltage, y = log(log(Amplification)))) +
  geom_line(aes(y = fitted(fit), size=2)) 
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (6): y, size, x
```

Comment: just `filter` them out. `APD %>% filter(Serial_number == 608004650) %>% ggplot(aes(...))`

Comment: Hi @RichardTelford, thank you! When I do this I receive the error "Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Column `Threshold` is unknown".

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example with some sample data? Your comment is a bit confusing because the column `Threshold` isn't mentioned in the code you've provided.

Comment: maybe `filter(Serial_number == "608004650")` as `Serial_number` is a factor?

Comment: @Greg Indeed, I forgot it on my own that I created a data frame with "Threshold" at the beginning..  Sorry. I added the missing lines.
Will also add a reproducible example soon!

Comment: @Antonis Unfortunately, this does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a workaround:

```
APD$SN<- "No"
APD$SN[APD$Serial_number == 912009895]<- "Yes"
One_APD<- subset(APD, SN=="Yes")
ggplot(One_APD, aes(x = Voltage, y = log(log(Amplification)))) +
  geom_point(size=3, colour="blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = pred, size=0.5, alpha=0.2, colour="red")) + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

Though it works I'm surprised there isn't something like "Drop levels which are FALSE"..